# How to Initialize php variable with javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, variables, google-schemas

Hello i have email that i sent to my clients that look like:
`$body = '<div>my email content</div>';`
and i need to add to $body variable this script from google api:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "LodgingReservation",
  "reservationNumber": "abc456",
  "reservationStatus": "http://schema.org/Confirmed",
  "underName": {
    "@type": "Person",
    "name": "John Smith"
  },
  "reservationFor": {
    "@type": "LodgingBusiness",
    "name": "Hilton San Francisco Union Square",
    "address": {
      "@type": "PostalAddress",
      "streetAddress": "333 O'Farrell St",
      "addressLocality": "San Francisco",
      "addressRegion": "CA",
      "postalCode": "94102",
      "addressCountry": "US"
    },
    "telephone": "415-771-1400"
  },
  "checkinDate": "2017-04-11T16:00:00-08:00",
  "checkoutDate": "2017-04-13T11:00:00-08:00"
}
</script>
```

how can i do that? any ideas?
i can not change " to '.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood the question, this should be what you looking for:

```php
$script = <<<EOF
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "LodgingReservation",
  "reservationNumber": "abc456",
  "reservationStatus": "http://schema.org/Confirmed",
  "underName": {
    "@type": "Person",
    "name": "John Smith"
  },
  "reservationFor": {
    "@type": "LodgingBusiness",
    "name": "Hilton San Francisco Union Square",
    "address": {
      "@type": "PostalAddress",
      "streetAddress": "333 O'Farrell St",
      "addressLocality": "San Francisco",
      "addressRegion": "CA",
      "postalCode": "94102",
      "addressCountry": "US"
    },
    "telephone": "415-771-1400"
  },
  "checkinDate": "2017-04-11T16:00:00-08:00",
  "checkoutDate": "2017-04-13T11:00:00-08:00"
}
</script>
EOF;

$body = '<div>my email content</div>' . $script;
```

More about [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

Probably you'll need to use htmlentities() method to encode special characters

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear , any ways i think this is what you are looking for.
You can Use Ajax, use Jquery ajax `$.ajax({});` 
for implementing cross browser ajax support in your website.Send that array using ajax to the php file which you implemented the mail functionality. Just use the `$_GET` OR `$_POST` for getting the data. Then append the data in to your mail body.

See the underlying link for reading the jquery ajax documentation.
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/